# Create a bootable Ubuntu USB for PC from my Mac

Tags: macos, ubuntu, boot, usb

I've searched the web for hours trying to find out the following:

I am having problems with Nautilis.  I want to create a Ubuntu Boot-USB for PC's.  However I own a PC with Ubuntu 13.04 (the Disk manager is broken) and a Mac.  How can I get the ISO extracted to the USB to boot on my PC?

I don't want Windows, and I don't want to boot Ubuntu on my Mac - simple.

FYI - The problem was, in fact, the DELL PC that this bootable USB was being used on.  UNetBootin was perfectly fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest using a command line utility, `dd`.

1. Attach the USB that you intend to use, note that this process will fully wipe it.
2. List the drives/partitions with `diskutil list` (find the `/dev/disk#`)
3. Run `dd if=/Users/USERNAME/Downloads/ubuntu-13.04x64.iso of=/dev/disk# bs=1M`

Once that appears to be done, type `sync` and make sure your drive is written to.  That should be all you need, just be sure to not mistype anything - since you could kill your main drive by overwriting sectors.

Comment: @user238206 - Not sure what `Nautilus` has to do with you wanting to make a bootable drive for PC... In any case, `dd` is a bit-for-bit copy, so it's slow.  If that doesn't work, then you probably have something else wrong - since unetbootin doesn't work and this doesn't.  I would suggest giving it a bit longer before cutting it off.  Or booting a live ubuntu disk (you could do this in `virtualbox`) and running `dd` or run the `make a bootable usb` option.

Comment: If Nautilus wasn't broken, I could quickly create a ubuntu live disk from my ubuntu installation.  Nevertheless, I can try the dd method a second time, surely this could take hours? When previously on Nautilus (<= 12.*) it took about 5-10 minutes max.

Comment: One more problem I have found is When I use the Disk Util to erase the flash drive and create a bootable partition using the FAT32 filesystem, using the `dd` command will then reset the filesystem to being the Mac OS Extended (Journaled)

Comment: `dd` doesn't do formatting in the traditional sense, it will bit-for-bit copy the iso - so whatever the ISO is, the flash drive will be also.  You don't need to format it first nor make anything bootable using DD, since DD will overwrite whatever is on the drive on a sector level.  It may take longer than 10mins using the `bs=1M` option (but you can usually leave it out for live discs), but not hours - no.  You could always install another DE and create a bootable USB from there, or as I said before, run a `Virtualbox`.

Comment: It irritates me that something so simple, requires a rather perplexed solution, Virtualbox or other Desktop Environment with the ability to create live disks, it's absurd.  I guess I will figure this out one way or another I refuse to spend hours pissing about when it's a very very simple thing i want to do...

Comment: Verify the `md5` of your download - could be that you have a corrupted image since ways that are generally bullet proof aren't working.  Virtualbox is a simple solution since you aren't getting it done this way, all you would need to do is install vbox.  Then you boot off the iso you *already have downloaded and verified*, and make the image from a live disc.  It would take about as much effort as anything else...

Comment: You have a fair point about virtualbox actually, I didn't see it like that.  As for the `md5sum` i downloaded the .iso directly from ubuntu.com/ 13.04 (64bit of course)

Comment: @user238206 - MD5 is always worth checking, it's provided to verify data integrity (not just to make sure the source didn't change things).  There could have been an error on the server, in the pipeline, or locally on your computer causing you to get a byte or so out of order (or not at all), meaning that you could potentially have a bad disc causing unnecessary headaches.

Comment: I've never checked these before, so how does one go about doing this?

Comment: [Google](http://www.google.com) suggests [this](http://osxdaily.com/2009/10/13/check-md5-hash-on-your-mac/).  In short, open terminal and type: `md5 /path/to/your/file.iso`.  This is getting too long here, so once you get more rep we can go to chat - otherwise, we need to cut it off (as per SuperUser's suggestion).

Comment: Okay - although, I understand the reasoning behind md5 checksum, regardless, i'll read-up on it more and as for the extrcting ISO I shall assume your suggestion is valid as i've done this before many occasions, but in this instance there is another technical fault.

Comment: You don't need to extract the iso.  DD is a copy of the iso to a drive.  Extracting it would ruin what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu provides step by step instructions on how to accomplish this

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

by [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/), you can make flash disks bootable in linux distros

Comment: That didn't seem to work, sadly when I attempt to boot the usb it says 'no boot device rarara'.  It seemed promising at first, but no idea.

Comment: I had the same problem.